# removing lines with certain fields in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sh, csv

I have a tab delimited file which has 20 columns and 40 rows

```
missense 
nonsense
5' UTR
3' UTR
```

so they are in column 9 and i request that only lines with certain values remain in my output but when performing this i get nothing in output
So if the value is missense or nonsense keep those lines otherwise remove them

```
awk -F"\t" '$9 == "missense" || $9 == "nonsense" ' input > output
```

I have also tried

```
awk -F"\t" '$9 == "missense"' || ' $9 == "nonsense" ' input > output
```

all answers come up with 0 bytes.

Comment: your first line should work, does your `$9` have leading/trailing space? try `print $9` see if you were checking the right col.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a match instead of equality:

```
awk -F"\t" '$9 ~ "missense" || $9 ~ "nonsense" ' input > output
```

This is not a good choice if you want 'this-missense-too' omitted from the output, but otherwise avoids issues with leading or trailing spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your file has spaces along with tabs. Try this:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]+' '$9 == "missense" || $9 == "nonsense"' input > output
```